# What is the formula to divide a set of squares into powers of 2? (Javascript)(canvas)

Tags: javascript, html, math, canvas

**Final Edit:** SUCCESS!

As previously stated in my comment below Michael's  answer, I was not accounting for the fact I had multiplied the amount of rows by the width of my squares.

***The full correct formula to size the canvas and arrange these squares is as follows:***

```
var canvasWidth = squareWidth * Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numberOfSquares));

var canvasHeight = squareHeight * Math.ceil(numberOfSquares / (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numberOfSquares))));
```

**Original Post:**

I used to know this and it's something simple that I'm overlooking but I've spent two hours on this one thing now and it's driving me nuts!

Say I have a canvas element in HTML5 and I have four images/squares (all the same size):

**[ ][ ][ ][ ]**

All I know at this point is their width/height and the amount of squares I have.

**What is the formula to set my canvas to the size of these squares when I arrange them like this:**

**[ ][ ]**

**[ ][ ]**

To be clear, I want to know how many columns there will be, how many rows there will be and the width/height of the canvas to wrap them.

**Edit**: I forgot to mention that I am trying to get them in powers of two.  So,  2,4,8,16,24..etcetc I realise that there will be blank  spaces, I don't care about them I simply want to size the canvas to accommodate equal rows on both sides

The equation I've forgotten sorts any number of squares, be it odd,even or just 1

I thought it was something like:

```
var canvasWidth = (squareWidth*howManySquares)/2;
var canvasHeight = (squareHeight*howManySquares)/2;
```

This works to an extent but the /2 will half a canvas with only 1 square.
I think I tried `ceil()` at some point but I'm completely muddled up now.

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

**Edit2:**

Thanks to Michael Lawrie, I'm getting closer to the answer.

To be even more clear as to what I'm after (as I forgot there was more than one approach to this..) I want Michael Lawrie's second suggestion, where I find out how many times I can neatly split the squares to make a squre-ish rectangular canvas to try and remove as many empty slots as possible.

his answer was half- correct but he forgot to include the squares width like so:

```
 canvasWidth = squareWidth * Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(howManySquares));
```

This one works ( I think? I only tested small numbers so far.. correct me if I'm wrong please) but it's only the width.

I'm now having problems finding the height. copying the width version for `boxHeight` doesn't work (as expected) and my shoddy attempts at tweaking Michael Lawrie's version yielded no results either..

So I'm still stuck. Ihanks for the help so far, Almost got it!

Comment: How would you arrange three images? Three columns and one row? Three rows and one column? Two columns and two rows, with a blank spot? How would you arrange seven images?

Comment: Oh, right, I forgot to mention that I am trying to get them in powers of two.  So,  2,4,8,16,24..etcetc I realise that there will be blank  spaces, I don't care about them I simply want to size the canvas to accommodate equal rows on both sides

Comment: So seven images will be arranged in a 4x4 square? As in, the first row will have 4 images, the second will have 3, and the remaining two rows will be empty?

Comment: @kevin I think Michael Lawrie had it. Looks like it at least.. I'll check later, I have to take a break, my head hurts.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you always want a square, even if that square is not full, both the width and height should be `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number_of_squares))`. If you want a rectangle with unequal sides, it's slightly more complicated:

```
var long_side = Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(number_of_squares));
var short_side = Math.ceil(number_of_squares / long_side);
```

This gives you the size of your canvas in squares. Multiply by the pixel dimension of your squares to get the final size for your canvas.

Comment: It might just be me, but I think your Math for your second method is slightly wrong, the long side (width) works perfectly but the short side is off.. additionally you forgot to include the width/height of the boxes themselves so implementing this code would return a value of 0 every time as-is. I'll update my question with an update and my shoddy attempt at fixing it, thanks for your answer by the way =)

Comment: No problem. It shouldn't give you a value of zero unless you have 0 squares. It gives you the dimension of your box in square units; just multiply by your particular pixel width/height to get your canvas dimensions. Can you give me an example of a number of squares where the short side calculation is wrong?

Comment: Certainly =)  the Y of the canvas does not  go down when there are 3 squares. The code I used is: `var canvasHeight =  squareHeight * Math.ceil(numberOfSquares / canvasWidth);`

Comment: `Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(3)) == 2; Math.ceil(3/2) == 2`. For 3 squares that gives you a 2x2 grid, no?

Comment: A-Ha!  That SHOULD give me that answer but i'm using variables not numbers. We both forgot yet again to take into account the width of the squares.

The reason it wasn't working is because I was referencing `canvasWidth` AFTER having multiplied the  `boxWidth`. So the correct line for the height should be: `var canvasHeight = boxHeight * Math.ceil(numberOfSquares /  (Math.ceil(Math.sqrt(numberOfSquares))));`

Thank you very much for your help, I believe my problem is fixed =D